# 0 results on query even though rows exist in Database = 2 databases, but why 2?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework (4.3) and code first (along with SQL server 2012 localdb).

I'm having an interesting situation where in one application a call returns a result ('card') and another using the same query on the same db (with thousands of rows available) returns nothing (null in this case since I'm using FirstOrDefault).

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())
        {
            //verify account exists
            var account = context.Account.SingleOrDefault(a => a.AccountNum == accountNum);

            if (account == null)
            {   
                //handle no account                 
                return false;
            }                

            var card = context.cards.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Used == false);

            //check that we actually got a card
            if (card == null)
            { 
                //handle no cards available
                return false;
            }

            card.Used = true;

           //snip...

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

<s>In my test console app 'card' will have a value, while in my "service" it does not. Same code (same assembly even), same db, same rows available. The account retrieval works in both cases.</s>

I am going to try this:
[How to force EF Code First to query the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657643/how-to-force-ef-code-first-to-query-the-database)

But even if that works the inconsistent behaviour doesn't make sense to me.

**EDIT**:

Ends up I have two database instance as pointed out. The interesting part is the datasource changes depending on where the library is run from (as debug under VS11 or from a service running as the admin user). Here's my app.config:

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

When I attached to the service process running the same library (DLL) as the console application the datasource has changed from:

```
(localdb)\v11.0
```

To:

```
.\SQLEXPRESS
```

Same DLL, same app.config. I vaguely remember reading something about named vs unamed local db instances and what user they are run under, however my google skills are failing me currently.

So when I open a connection in SSMS I need to use the appropriate server name depending on which db I'm working with. Not a big deal as this is just the setup for development.

My question:

- Does anyone know where this is documented?

Comment: Make sure you are using the same database. To me it looks like the app that does not return anything created its own database it is using. The database is empty so you don't see any results.

Comment: It's the only db. As I stated the account request works in both cases (so I must be on the same db). If the database was empty I wouldn't be getting the accounts that exist in the db.

Comment: Please show the connection strings for both the app and the service. I'm willing to bet that at least one of them is using `User Instances` and/or `AttachDbFileName`. In which case you are connecting to two different copies of the same database.

Comment: You are both correct. I was thrown off by the accounts as I was creating the same accounts in both dbs. They are running under differnt users, so the end up being different dbs (first time using localdb). A little embarassing :$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was using two databases. Two were being used as I didn't have a .config in the actual running folder with the connection string for my service. The test application had a .config with

```
  <entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
             <parameter value="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
        </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
```

The service did not and therefore fell on the default behaviour (which appears is connecting to the default instance of SQL Server).

I would have rather had the application fail to create the DB (throwing an exception) without a connection explicitly stated, however it is documented by Microsoft in the 'remarks' section of [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

> If no connection string is found, then the name is passed to the DefaultConnectionFactory registered on the Database class. The connection factory then uses the context name as the database name in a default connection string. (This default connection string points to .\SQLEXPRESS on the local machine unless a different DefaultConnectionFactory is registered.)