# Entity Framework 6 query returning record with data not yet saved in the database

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I created a very simple test project using Entity Framework 6 Code-first and I'm trying to understand how change tracking works.

In my simple test I have a Blogs table and I insert a Blog with a name "User1", after inserting and saving I modify the object used to insert (name="User1 modified") but without saving changes. Right after that I query my database. For my surprise the query from the db is returning the modified record  even though I did not save my changes after the update. Why is that?

Here my code:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new BloggingContext())
        {
            // Create and save a new Blog 
            Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Blog: ");
            //var name = Console.ReadLine();

            var name = "User1";

            var blog = new Blog { Name = name };
            db.Blogs.Add(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();

            //Modify my blog name but don't save changes yet!
            blog.Name = "User1 modified";

            // Display all Blogs from the database 
            var query = from b in db.Blogs
                        orderby b.Name
                        select b;

            Console.WriteLine("All blogs in the database:");
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                //item.Name comes as "User1 modified" instead of "User1" Why?????
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        } 
    }
}
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get the data directly from the database instead of the Context, which seems to be holding my object properties even without saving changes?

Thanks!

The original project tutorial can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx

Comment: Why do you want to query a previous state of your model?  If you need to "remember" something about your data from before you changed it, do your queries before your modifications and store the relevant information in a variable.

Comment: Is hard to explain. I'm working on an Integration test where I insert an Insured object, then I modify a property and I run a method that gets my insureds from the db and compares the new to the existing record but in this case existing and new are the same because I'm reusing the context. In the live app won't happen because I do create a new context on each web transaction, but I want to build a test that covers that use case.

Comment: In this test, if the object has changed (existing != new) then I need to create a new record to keep history. But that is not possible because existing will always be == new when reusing Context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up querying my entities `AsNoTracking` as suggested by @LadislavMrnka:

```
var query = from x context.YourEntities.AsNoTracking() where ... select x;
```

[How to force EF Code First to query the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657643/how-to-force-ef-code-first-to-query-the-database)

That forces EF to reload the data each time. It works in my case because I only need to read some data form my returning objects and I'm not saving any changes.

Answer (score 2):

The `DbContext` is a [unit of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) and it is a feature that it returns the same object as you already have loaded. The `DbContext` caches all objects loaded and provides one consistent view of the data which you can update and later save in one call to `SaveChanges()`.

If you want to do separate queries from the database that don't take unsaved changes into consideration you should do that using another `DbContext`.

Comment: The problem is that in my current architecture I'm only using one `DbContext`. So there's no way to query data that has not been committed through `SaveChanges` other than using a new `DbContext`?

Comment: No, and you should not use only one `DbContext`. It is intended to be light weight and only used for the duration of a single "unit of work" which is typically one logical save operation from the user perspective (which might update several tables in the DB).

Comment: you can do `dataContext.Entry(entityVariable).Reload();` - this will reload the given entity from the database and overwriting local changes