# How DbContext is able fetch the entity that I just added without calling SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, database-migration, dbcontext

I am implementing migration tool using EF 6.
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
            var count = targetContext.Orders.Count(); //return 0

            sourceContext.DetachEntity(srcOrder);
            targetContext.Orders.Add(srcOrder);

            var count2 = targetContext.Orders.Count();  //return 0

            var destOrder = targetContext.Orders.Find(srcOrder.Id); //still returns correct/not-null value
            some more code.....

            destOrder?.Attachments.Add(attachment); // is this right way
```

I am trying to get recently added entity (for mapping navigation properties and joins) without calling savechanges() method and It WORKS. Even though the count and count2 both returns 0, I still get not-null object from `targetContext.Orders.Find(srcOrder.Id)`

I found relatable answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207702/entity-framework-6-query-returning-record-with-data-not-yet-saved-in-the-databas) but I am still not sure if it will correctly save **OrderAttachment** mapping and is safe way to use entity this way.

Comment: I'm almost positive EF uses the Identity Map pattern (https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html). This is a widely known pattern across ORMs.

Comment: People say We should not use only one DbContext. It is intended to be light weight and only used for the duration of a single "unit of work" which is typically one logical save operation. But hey, this is migration tool. it will be used only once OR once per release maybe.